# Are PGI Compilers pre-installed in google colab?

Tags: compilation, gpu, google-colaboratory, pgi

I have been trying to install a GPU-based [scientific software](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e-gpu/-/wikis/home), that necessitated the need for PGI compilers. And since Google Colab has a GPU I would like to use that as a platform to install the software. But I'm not sure if PGI compiler is preinstalled on Google Colab. If it is then how can I check that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observed?

Comment: @BobSmith Hi. I just wanted to know if there's a way to check if PGI compilers are pre-installed in Google Colab through some bash commands. For example to check for the Nvidia toolkit we could use !nvidia-smi. I wanted to know if there's something in those lines or It would be helpful to know where codes installed in google colab are located. Then it would be as simple as checking that bin folder for pgi compilers.